# axes swapped and zooming without losing aspect

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm confused about the next figure
[image]

because it was expected the values be in the other axis, i.e.: the scales should be swapped since the price expected was 100 and the amount 35 (x and y represents what is meant to be, but the values are swapped).

I don't know what is missing here, this should be conceptual, but since I cant find it,

- How can be swapped the values of the axis, so the common point represents a price of 100,000 and an amount of 35?(instead of 35000 and 100)
- Is there a way to get the coordinates of the intersection of the point?

  ````
   \usepackage{pgfplots}
   \pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
   \usetikzlibrary{intersections}
   \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
   \begin{axis}[legend style={at={(0.5,-0.1)},anchor=north},
       axis lines = middle,
       xmax=200, ymin=0,
       xlabel = $Quantity$,
       ylabel = {$Price$},
       title=Orange market,
      % label style={anchor=north east},
       x tick label style = {font = \small, text width = 1cm, align = center, rotate = 0, anchor = north east},
       extra x ticks = {0},
       ytick={0,10 000,...,60 000},
       scaled y ticks=false,
       ticklabel style = {font=\footnotesize},
       yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
       enlargelimits={0.15,upper},
   %
       domain=0:200, no marks,
       every axis plot post/.append style={thick, dashed},
               ]
   \addplot +[name path=A] {10000+250*x} node[right]{$O$};
   \addplot +[name path=B] {50000-150*x} node[right]{$D$};
   \fill [fill=brown,name intersections={of=A and B, by=a},total=\t,]
          (a) circle[radius=1.5pt];
   \addlegendentry{$Offer$}
   \addlegendentry{$Demand$}

   \end{axis}
   %\draw[->] (0,0) -- (5,0) node[below] {Qty};
   %\draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,5) node[left] {$};
   %\coordinate (p1) at (0.55,0.55);
   %\draw [-{Stealth}] (1,1)--(2,2); 
   %\draw [-{Stealth}] (2,2)--(1,1); 
       \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}```
  ````

Comment: You got exactly what the code states. The formula is `10000 + 250*x`, so for x = 0 you get 10000. Please note that the shown `10,000` is 10000 and not 10. The comma is the (English) thousand separator ...